# Как спрятать блок select который :focus?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

У меня есть кастомный select. По нажатию, библиотека jQuery генерирует выдающий список. Все работает хорошо, только хочу знать, как скрыть блок по котому нажали?

```
<div   class="strip_bg ">
        <div class="strip_bg_grad">
            <form  action="">
                <select  name="dropdown_of_mine" id="demo-select_1"  >
                    <option value="1" data-modifier="mod" class="hide" selected >ГГГГ</option>
                    <option value="2">1999</option>
                    <option value="4">2000</option>
                    <option value="5">2001</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Скрипт генерирует новый список извлекая option так что на время пока option не будет выбран ГГГГ выводиться дважды, и его надобно убрать, скрыть.

Comment: может у вас класс `.hide` не объявлен? Т.к. изначально ваше поле не должно быть видно

Comment: option - особые блоки, они по-моему не починяются стилям, скрыть возможно можно из-под js, перехватив событие droplist или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: нужно весь код видеть - что у вас в js а что в html , желательно полностью выложить в сниппете , и дополнительно на codepen